# Adding ticks along circumference of circle using JSXGraph

Tags: php, jsxgraph

I want to add ticks along circumference of circle using JSXGraph

p1 = board.create("point",[-50,20],{visible:true, fixed:true, showInfobox:false,withLabel:false}); p2 = board.create("point",[130,20],{visible:false, fixed:true, showInfobox:false,withLabel:false});
board.create("circle",[p1,p2]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSXGraph just supports ticks for straight lines and segments out of the box. But you can build a "ticks curve". You can see an example at http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wiki/index.php/Circle_with_ticks. The ticks are formed by a single curve, which is interrupted by NaNs.